# get height of document content including scroll bars javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the key question: ***How do you get the accurate offset top of an element (in this case text boxes) when scroll bars are present?*** Preferably all in javascript.

I have a page which will overflow the height of the browser window, which means there will be scroll bars. I have textboxes throughout the page with onblur events linked. Onblur the it will validate the value of the textobx. If the data is not valid. If not then it will/should move a speech bubble right on top of the textbox with an error message. element.offsettop doesn't seem to take into account any scroll bars which may be present on the page.

thank you! Please let me know if you don't understand what I'm asking.

***Edit:***

Can someone help me to find the height of the DOCUMENT CONTENT. Not the window height but the document content height so it will also include the height with scroll bars? Thanks!

Comment: When you say "all in javascript" do you mean javascript purely, or is a javascript framework such as jQuery permissible?

Comment: I would like the answer in pure javascript

Comment: _“Can someone help me to find the height of the DOCUMENT CONTENT”_ – http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+document+height

Answer (score 7):

Document sizes are a browser compatibility nightmare because, although all browsers expose clientHeight and scrollHeight properties, they don't all agree how the values are calculated.

There used to be a complex best-practice formula around for how you tested for correct height/width. This involved using document.documentElement properties if available or falling back on document properties and so on.

The simplest way to get correct height is to get all height values found on document, or documentElement, and use the highest one. This is basically what jQuery does:

```
var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;

var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                       html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
```

Comment: okey. Thank you. I think I've seen that code somewhere else, but now I know what it does. One more question: does element.offsetTop take into account scroll bars that may be present? Thanks. You have been very helpful. I'll continue to do some digging to see if I can figure out more...